# Issue with PHP + Ajax + Sql

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

I'm sure it is just a simple issue, I have looked in the forums but couldn't find an example that was specific to my issue.

Basically I am displaying a table of hrefs, which each have an onclick() call to an ajax method, using a 'get' and a url.

```
function createRequestObject(){
var req;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    //For IE 5+
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else{
    //Error for an old browser
    alert("Your browser is not IE 5 or higher, or Firefox or Safari or Opera");
}
return req;
}


//Make the XMLHttpRequest Object
var http = createRequestObject();



function sendRequest(method, url){
if(method == "get" || method == "GET"){
    http.open(method,url,true);

    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}
}
function handleResponse(){
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
    var response = http.responseText;
    if(response){

        document.getElementById("DIVNAME").innerHTML = response;

    }
}
}
```

The call for an href looks like:

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onClick="sendRequest(\'get\', \''.$toPass.'\')"/>'.$variable.'</a></td>';
```

The `$toPass` variable is `page.php?variable1='.$variable1.'&variable2='.$variable2.'&variable3=blah&action='.$option.'`

When I pass a variable 1 for example : 'TP111010114' it works fine, the _REQUEST['variable1']; grabs the variable and pushes it the through my sql request.

if the variable contains a # for example : 'Blah #2' the only piece of data that gets through is
Variable 1 = 'Blah ' with the remaining variables being unassigned. 
From what it looks like it is not getting anything after the #.
I tried encoding the url in php, then unescaping it in my ajax.js where you call window.open('get', unescape(url), true); but I had the same result, it worked with any variable that didn't contain #. When I tried to encode it using urlencode() and not decoding it in my ajax.js, the request was not going through.

The encoded request looks like:

```
page.php%3Fvariable1%3DTP111010114%26variable2%3D64%26variable3%3Dnew%26Action%3DOthers
```

if it is not encoded it looks like:

```
page.php?variable1=TP111010114&variable2=64&variable3=new&Action=Others
```

I used firebug to monitor the .js variables as they go through and it looks as though when I encode it that it should grab the proper variable, but it still only grabs before the # in the variable

```
http://www.randomsite.ca/page.php?variable1=WF225+Amendment+#2&variable2=543&variable3=new&Action=Others
```

Yet this request on the php side still gets $variable = $_REQUEST['variable1']
$variable = 'WF225 Amendment ', and the other variables are unnassigned.

It must be something to do with the way something is handling the #, but I do not see what I am missing here, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

*I have renamed information for privacy purposes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `urlencode` the values you're putting into the URL, not the whole URL including variable names. You want to encode the "blah #2" but not the "&variable1=" part. Ex:

```
$toPass = 'page.php?variable1=' . urlencode($variable1) . '&variable2=' . urlencode($variable2) ...etc
```

You won't need any decoding on the HTML/JS end.

Comment: ... and OP also needs to NOT roll their own AJAX handler, but use something premade like jquery or mootools, which handle all those nitpicky little details for you.

Comment: That may be helpful, but it would not have fixed this problem in the PHP code generating the initial HTML page, where this change needs to be made.

Comment: Thanks so much Dan, exactly what I needed. Worked immediately, good to know.

Comment: haha took me a second to find that checkmark... Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe that it may be parsing anything after the # as a named anchor which will likely disregard the variables after this point... have you tried using a method that doesn't rely on the # character? Or even try using POST as the AJAX method?

Comment: I created a new option in my ajax.js that would handle posts. The code is :




     else{
  method = 'POST';
  http.open(method,unescape(url),true);
 
  http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
  http.send(null);
  
 }




I still got the same issue of everything after the # in the first variable in the post being cut off.